# Creating a .reg file for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry

I created a .reg file but when I double-click it, it doesn't want to be imported.

> The specified file is not a registry script.You can only import binary
>   registry files from within the registry editor.

Here is the content of the .reg file

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\PngCrush]
@=”PNG Crush”

[HKEY_CLASSES-ROOT\Folder\shell\PngCrush\command]
@=”E:\Programs\PNGCrush\crush.bat %1”
```

Could someone help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how those quotes ended up in that file, but I would assume those don't work (maybe you copied it off a Wordpress blog).

Besides anything else, I think it should be like this:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\PngCrush]
@="PNG Crush"

[HKEY_CLASSES-ROOT\Folder\shell\PngCrush\command]
@="E:\Programs\PNGCrush\crush.bat %1"
```

Comment: +1 Could be, perhaps he did some international input that uses different characters.

Comment: I didn't notice that! You're right I copied it off the net, thank you!

Answer (score 36):

That's not the valid syntax of a registry file, it's missing the header.

Add a line in front with: `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`

Check whether there are invalid characters, if you saved the file in Unicode that could be the problem.

Comment: But aximili shouold be sure that this file is unicode. REGEDIT4 should be used for ansi files.

Comment: @crea7or: The file does not need to be Unicode for what he is trying to insert.

Comment: This answer is the correct one.

Comment: As Gras Double says, this answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 9):

Just compiling all the answers together with some extra info I discovered.

Header on the first line:
`Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`

- A blank line between keys delimited by "CRLF"
- keys brackets without spaces
- values in double quotes
- integer/word values in hex - lowercase for the letters apparently

Example

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyOrg]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyOrg\MyKey]
"My Value"="Some String"
"My Flag or Integer"=dword:00000001
```

The allowed encodings also seems to correspond to the Windows API strings which are:

- 8-bit fixed width: Windows-1252 - almost the same as ISO-8859-1
- 16-bit fixed width: UCS-2LE (little endian) - basically the same as UTF-16

Note: when a text editor says "unicode" for the encoding, it probably means UTF-8 which is a variable width encoding not naively compatible with internal Windows.

Note 2 (edit): ASCII is 7-bit and all the processors I know of in use are a power of 2 bits so it's always going to be wrapped in some other ASCII superset like 1252. #thingsyoulearnafteruni

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this website, it helped me with this problem: [“The specified file is not a registry script” – How encoding can ruin your morning](http://crmdev.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/the-specified-file-is-not-a-registry-script-how-encoding-can-ruin-your-morning/)

> Turns out that encoding can ruin your morning. Taking a look at the message I saw the “… only import binary registry files from …” and I thought “Why does this thing think it’s binary?”. Why, indeed. I opened the file back up in TextPad and rather than just hitting Ctrl+S or Save, I chose "Save As". Doing so presented this menu, and I’ve highlighted my problem:
>
> [image]
>
> That’s right. Without me doing anything, TextPad was going to save this file as Unicode. Regedit expects to get .reg files that are ANSI encoded. So I changed the Encoding to ANSI, saved the file, ran it again, and everything worked fine. It caused me some frustration for a good 20 minutes, so hope this helps someone else out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because I saved it as UTF-8-BOM. It should be UTF-8 without BOM (Byte Order Mark). It's worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [REG utility](http://www.petri.co.il/reg_command_in_windows_xp.htm) to manipulate registry via command line, if it fits your needs.