# Windows 7 - Add shell command for .png file

Tags: windows-7, shell, windows-registry, context-menu

On Windows XP, you could go to Folder Options - File Types, select PNG, create a new action, such as this

```
Action: Crush
Application: "F:\Programs\PNGCrush\crush.bat" "%1"
```

So you can right click on a `.png` file and select *Crush*.

How do you do this on Windows 7?  I assume through `regedit` or `.reg` file, but how?

EDIT: Thank you for all your replies... but I'd like to avoid "Open With" or 3rd party program if possible.

Comment: Asked [Creating a .reg file for Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/404572/creating-a-reg-file-for-windows-7) again?

Comment: Hey again Tom! Now that I can run a .reg file (thanks to you), now I am asking how to write a .reg file that does the above (ie. the script). Fyi, the .reg file on my previous post doesn't work, I was just curious why I couldn't run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a new item to the Right-click context menu of **.png** files, you add a new key and `command` subkey to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pngfile\shell\` in the Registry.

Based on your example, importing the following **.reg** file should work:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pngfile\shell\PNGCrush]
@="Crush"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pngfile\shell\PNGCrush\command]
@="\"F:\\Programs\\PNGCrush\\crush.bat\" \"%1\""
```

Comment: This looks promising, thanks a lot! I successfully inserted it into the registry. But why can't still I see the "Crush" menu?? I could add a context menu to a folder the same way. I've restarted my computer.

Comment: It should apply immediately, and should be visible when you right-click a PNG file. Alternatively, you can add these keys to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell`. If you look at some of the keys in there, you should see the pattern. If I've made a mistake, let me know! :)

Comment: I got it! It's `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ACDSee Pro 5.png\shell`. Why is the name so non-standard, did ACDSee change it? Anyway it works, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to click on png file with right mouse button, select **Open With**, then browse to your bat file. Do not forget to remove check "Use this program as default".

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible through the registry, it can get complicated. I'd recommend [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) - it's pretty intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

FileTypesMan will work, but it's a bit dated and isn't as robust as [door2windows](http://www.door2windows.com/ultimate-windows-context-menu-customizer-customize-context-menu-in-windows-xp-vista-7/) equivalent product, which I like best.