# Why shell commands for PNG file in Windows 8 doesn't work?

Tags: windows-8, shell, windows-registry, context-menu, png

I have exactly same task like here:
[Windows 7 - Add shell command for .png file](https://superuser.com/questions/404861/windows-7-add-shell-command-for-png-file)

But this solution doesn't work in Windows 8 for unknown reason **only for PNG files**. And I don't know why.

I tried some other formats, PSD for example. Adding new commands works fine:

[image]

But exactly same commands for PNG don't show up in Windows Explorer:

[image]

I tried rename of class and commands, or use only user structure **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes**. I tried edit access rights permissions also. Nothing helps.

I suppose that there are some MIME type commands assigned to PNG format, but where I can find them in registry? Or something else?

**Update**:

I tried **FileTypesMan** and **Types** apps also. Some standart commands is listed, custom commands also here, but none of them work:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried any of the other proposed answers from the other question?

Comment: Those two examples aren't the same.  PhotoShop.Image.9 is another registered type, I don't think you can just create a key under Classes as you've done for png.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg, yes. I tried FileTypesMan and none of commands don't work. Even standard ones.

Comment: @cjb110, no. I created key for ".xxx" under Classes with "MySuperXXXType" class below, add some custom command and all work fine. It's always worked in all previous versions of Windows. But same actions don't work for PNG for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried first deleting all entries for .PNG so that PNG images are not recognised by Windows at all?

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit late but after hours of research why this doesn't work on the `pngfile`, `giffile`, `jpegfile` and possible other file extensions which are considered graphics/pictures/images and therefore executed with the `Windows 8 Photo App`, I have found the cause.

The actual cause is the app itself, all graphics are opened with the `Windows 8 Photo App` by default and the context menu items are not displayed. However, after changing the default application to the standard `Windows 7 Photo Viewer`, the items were displayed and working as intended.

Hopefully this will help other people such as me who came from google but found no solution for this particular problem.

// 02.04.2014
Just found out that even though doing the things above doesn't really much help when it comes to `.gif` files. So I've looked where the photo app stores it's shell data and found it: The key is the name of the binary value located at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.gif\OpenWithProgids`. It's the file with the prefix `App` which is following some kind of encryption characters. Just look up this key and you will get straight to the shell key for the app. Make your changes and you should see the new context menu item popping up **if** you have set the `Windows 8 Photo App` as default program.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [Types](http://izt.name/apps/types/) utility, its a bit plain looking but handles any assocation stuff I've had to do.

One note with Windows 8 when you search for Types remember to select Settings from the right charm, as it installs as a control panel app.

Comment: Unfortunately this don't work. Types utility shows custom commands. But editing them does nothing. Even standard ones.