# Disable scrolling-icon

Tags: windows-7, icons, scrolling, synaptics-touchpad

How can I disable this scrolling icon?

[image]

Windows 7, Synaptics TouchPad

Comment: let me guess, are you on dell ?

Comment: yes, i am using a dell laptop.

Comment: Hi there. It's almost 2020 and Synaptics didn't fix this bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this forum topic](http://www.un4seen.com/forum/?topic=11698.msg81241#msg81241) there should be a registry key you can change:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPEnh]
"UseScrollCursor"=dword:00000000
```

> Just add this to registry. Either copy-paste the above text into
>   Notepad, save it as a .reg file and run it, or manually add it using
>   RegEdit (on my system, this value didn't exist, so I had to create it
>   manually). Afterwards, restart SynTPEnh.exe and SynTPHelper.exe (use
>   TaskManager to kill them, then restart them from the Synaptics
>   installation folder, which is usualy C:\Program
>   Files\Synaptics\SynTP). Or simply restart your system.

Comment: I somehow managed to disable this in my old windows installation without modifying any icon files. There must be a way.

Comment: And yes, I only want to remove the icon.

Comment: +1 - Also note that on Windows 7 the `.reg` file will have to start with `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1269100/146644 "https://superuser.com/a/1269100/146644") for reference.

Comment: This Registry hack works also on Windows 10.