# The scroll wheel icon gets stuck on the screen in Window 7

Tags: windows-7, mouse, cursor

My Windows 7 install has a strange problem where sometimes the scroll wheel icon for the mouse gets stuck on the screen.

It's hard to explain in words, so here's a picture (it's in the blank space on the right side, halfway down the screen).

[image: Picture of my problem.]

Comment: and My mouse is there, it's just like a ghost of my previus mouse stuck on my screen.

Comment: Does this help? http://superuser.com/questions/473325/disable-scrolling-icon

Comment: ^^^ This approach worked for me. Disabling the scrolling cursor is a quick fix, if you have registry editing permissions.

Answer (score 19):

Click start button > Type "Mouse". 
Now go to the pointer tab , Click on the arrow under "Schemes" and apply "Windows Aero(System Scheme)". 
Finally uncheck the box in front of "allow themes to change mouse pointer" .

This should work for you.

Comment: Didn't solve it for me

Comment: i switched to a new theme, then back to the original and it solved the issue for me. Running windows 10.

Comment: @2b77bee6-5445-4c77-b1eb-4df3e5 I also had success switching to Windows Basic and back in Windows 7

Comment: Every time this issue occurs, I forget the solution and stumble back to this answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Unchecking "allow themes to change mouse pointer" did not work for me. What did work on the other hand was the following solution (for Synaptics touch pads):

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/touchpad-scroll-icon-stuck-on-screen-after-windows/cfb19413-a853-471c-9087-a0c2cf979068

> run regedit, navigate to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPEnh in left pane, right click SynTPEnh, select New/DWORD Value. Name of the new key should be writable, Name it: UseScrollCursor , value should be zeros at default, no need to change (in my case). (Credit: Mr JGR)

Then I rebooted my computer and the icon was gone.

Comment: Note that you need to reboot before this solution works - it's not totally clear in the link. This other link is more clear: https://www.andreafortuna.org/lenovo/windows-10-fix-two-finger-scrolling-issue-for-synaptics-touchpads/

Comment: No need to reboot, just Log-Off and Log-In. It worked for me on Windows 10. Be aware that after applying this change you lose the scroll feedback cursor icons for both vertical and horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 4):

Try Ctrl+scroll(tried two fingers in my case)

Comment: How would that help?

Comment: This worked for me. Ctrl + sliding two fingers on the touchpad.

Answer (score 2):

This happens for me when, I scroll with the Touchpad at the same time, that I move my mouse around (but only on specific softwares).

None of the permanent fixes above worked for me (Windows 10) (adding `UseScrollCursor` in  regedit + changing shceme) but I can at least remove the stuck icons, each time it happens, by restarting the process `SynTPEnh.exe` in [Process Hacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/)

1. In Process Hacker, search for `syntpenh`
2. Right-click SynTPEnh.exe
3. Select restart

It's not a permanent fix, but it works.

[image]

---

*If you don't have Process Hacker and you don't want to install it*:

1. Open Task Manager, find `Synaptics TouchPad`, right-click and select open file location
2. Go back in Task Manager, right click the same process `Synaptics TouchPad` and select `End Task`
3. Go in the file explorer windows opened in step 1 and double click `SynTPEnh.exe`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue but I didn't have "Allow themes to change mouse pointer" checked. So I uncheck "Enable Pointer Shadow" and it works.

Comment: You might need to be converted to a comment, feel free to flag a mod and ask for this to be done until you earn enough rep to write comments... this is an easy and simple task too by the way.

Comment: Feels like an answer to me, even though it's written in a comment style.

Answer (score 0):

This is Windows 10 manual:

1. Press Windows logo.
2. Type "Mouse".
3. Click offered "Mouse settings".
4. Right side of screen blue lettered click "Additional mouse options".
5. In the new window find from the top options "Pointers".
6. In the centre of window find and click "Use Default".
7. On button click "Apply".

Is it working?

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution (it's probably not the best)

1. Press the Windows button
2. Type "Mouse"
3. Click "Change Mouse Pointer Size"
4. Make your mouse bigger
5. Make your mouse your original size again
6. The mouse should now be normal

I don't think this is permanent either

Answer (score -1):

reinstall the drivers for your "mouse" and/or pointing devices.