# Two finger scrolling causes icon to get stuck

Tags: windows-10, icons, scrolling, synaptics-touchpad

After upgrading to windows 10, I have this annoying problem.
 When I use two finger scrolling, the icon that appears during the scrolling gets stuck on screen.
 After 30-60 minutes of browsing I will have a few of those and the only way to get rid of them is to log out of windows.

I have an old Dell XPS 15 and it has a Synaptics PS/2 Port Touchpad with driver version 19.0.15.2

Comment: I had this problem, too. The answer here has the solution/workaround: https://superuser.com/a/1261552/103148

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a driver bug, which implies the fix, if is exists, is an updated driver.  Maybe there is one that is newer than what you have, even if it isn't meant for Win10.  (I don't know, maybe you have to install Win7 and then the driver, and then upgrade again.)

Have you tried "no driver?"--meaning the Microsoft generic mouse driver.

In general, you can force a driver (if Microsoft considers it valid for the device--which it does with a generic mouse driver for a generic mouse).  Go to Device Manager, select the device, Action/Properties, tab Driver, Update Driver, Browse..., Let me pick...  At this point, you will likely have a choice of your Synaptics driver or a HID and/or PS2 mouse.  The second is a Microsoft generic mouse driver.  Select it, click Next, etc.

Comment: I tried to uninstall the driver but Windows seems to re-install it straight away. It doesn't matter if I tell it to completely remove it

Comment: In general, if you "remove" a driver, Windows will try the same process it used in the first place to install it.  But THIS time, Windows will have a cached copy of the driver, so it won't even bother to ask you to point to a driver.  And, Windows is glad to use information on the internet (eg microsoft.com) about what the latest driver for given hardware is.  That is why I described the procedure where you explicitly select the generic mouse driver.  Once you explicitly pick a driver, Windows will consider that one to be a better driver to load at boot than one based on its own info.

Comment: Although I didn't manage to do this the way you described, the problem is fixed. I assume that completely removing the driver and letting Windows reinstall it was the way to go.

Comment: As I said, I don't expect "completely removing the driver" to be effective because Windows caches drivers (in a hard to find place) and restores them on reboot without asking.  But maybe they changed that awful behavior...