# Windows 7 Synaptic Touchpad scrolling Icon disable

Tags: windows-7, scrolling, synaptics-touchpad

After reading lot of answer at not able to find solution (I am posting question).
I want to disable synaptic scroll mouse icon.

Checked many solution and found one sensible [Disable scrolling icon](https://superuser.com/questions/473325/disable-scrolling-icon)

But I am not able to run **.reg** file as told in link solution:

[image: Error message]

Picture of error added.
**Is there any other way to disable the mini scroll icon?**

Comment: **These are the type of answers I am finding**

since you indicate the older synaptics drivers offer a more suitable icon than the newer drivers would be to contact SYNAPTICS because the icon isw hard coded intor their drivers.

They might have an add on or even a different driver that would make things more palatable for you.

http://www.synaptics.com/support

Comment: [Link1](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Disabling-quot-cursor-icons-quot-for-synaptics-touchpad/td-p/1028913)

[Link2](http://www.un4seen.com/)

[Link3](https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/how-to-change-scrolling-icon-for-mouse-515618/)

Could not find a proper solution anywhere

Comment: Did you try changing the icon for it (for an invisible one)

Comment: no such option please mention this in the answers section if it worked for you,maybe this works. Yes I know how to change the icon but by changing icon the whole layout of icons changes(even when not scrolling **no option specific for scroll icon change**)

Comment: I have the option, don't know how to get it to you :/

Comment: you may post the screen shots of that window how to get there.

Answer (score 2):

Do it manually, press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and run `regedit.exe` to open the Registry Editor.

1. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPEnh`
2. Create a new (empty) `DWORD (32-bit)` named `UseScrollCursor`.
3. Reboot.